# Update attribute in has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following relationship:

```
User has_many :relationships
     has_many :friends, :through => :relationships

Friend has_many :relationships

Relationship belongs_to :user, :friend
```

Now, I would like to update `friends` of an user, but also update attribute `weight` in `relationships`. How should I go about it?

I tried

```
Friend
accept_nested_attribute_for :relationships
```

and

```
  friend = my_user.friends.first
   #update info
   friend.update_attributes(:info => my_info, :relationship => {:weight => 1})
```

How should I look up at particular relationship between user and friends before updating its weight attribute?

Comment: can you add couple of entries from each table. better run the 'select * ...' from each table and update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the friend's relationship whose weight you are setting, because as your association states, there are many.

There are more than one way to do that. I would probably do:

```
friend = my_user.friends.first
relationship = my_user.relationships.where(:friend_id => friend.id).first
relationship.update_attributes(:weight => 1)
```